# How to use 2 legged oauth on Google Admin Directory API

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to write code to get all user accounts in our Google Apps domain using Google Admin Directory API with 2 Legged OAuth. Unfortunately, I can hardly find any documents or sample code for directory API. I tried the code below:

```
AdminService adminService = new AdminService();
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator  authenticator= new  Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator(mydomainName, domainConsumerSecret, adminId, mydomainName);
UsersResource usrRes = new UsersResource(adminService, authenticator);
UsersResource.ListRequest listReq =   usrRes.List();
Google.Apis.Admin.directory_v1.Data.Users  allUsers =  listReq .Fetch();
foreach (Google.Apis.Admin.directory_v1.Data.User usr in allUsers.UsersValue)
{ ...  }
```

But I got the 401 unauthorized error.
Then I tried the low level way using the old GData Lib.

```
Google.GData.Client.OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator authenticator = new OAuth2LeggedAuthenticator("MyAPP", mydomainName, domainConsumerSecret,adminId, mydomainName, "HMAC-SHA1");
HttpWebRequest request = authenticator.CreateHttpWebRequest("GET", new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=mydomain.com"));
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

the above code got the same 401 error.

Based on the source code of Directory API, I think 2LO is supported. However, I just cannot make it work. Anyone can help to point out my problem? Thanks.

Another question: Is the userid (xoauth_requestor_id parameter) necessary for 2LO directory API request? I know this parameter is required for other APIs when using 2LO, but not clear if it is required for the Directory and Provisioning API.

BTW: I would like to construct the 2LO HTTP requests from scratch without using any lib, but I haven't started this yet.  I need to make sure that 2LO works on the Directory API requests.

Comment: 2-legged Oauth 1.0 is deprecated. Unless you have a very specific reason for using it you should be using OAuth 2.0, possibly with Service Accounts instead.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I found the problem, the "API key" parameter is missing

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles across this, Google deprecated the Provisioning API about a month before the original post.  I recently had the same problem when trying to authorize API access to my Google Apps domain using the Admin Directory API.  After finally figuring it out, I decided to document it, and I'm actually in the midst of putting together a series on how to [make some sense out of Google Apps Directory API and OAuth 2.0](http://silverstar-media.com/google-apps-directory-api-explorer-oauth2/)...  Keep in mind that Google now strongly encourages the use of OAuth 2.0, so 2LO is a thing of the past, and the above "fix" may no longer be relevant.

In case folks don't want to click the link, I would recommend using Google's API Explorer to find out how a successful POST/GET request is formulated using specific APIs.  This saved me heaps of time.  Also, be forewarned, if you're trying to use the directory.users.list API and have thousands of accounts in the domain, it will take a very long time to retrieve the users.  I would suggest starting with the directory.users.get API to retrieve a specific user and check out what a successful API request/response looks like.

Comment: I wanted to use directory API to get list of users for a domain.The above method works but I was trying to get this with 1 legged auth. It didn’t work. I have few doubt about it.
1. Does 1LO is based on oauth1.0(which is deprecated) or it can be used with oauth2.0 as well?
2. [admin.google.com] In security->advanced settings->Manage Oauth client access I added my API client with scope to get access to data. But while making API request with that API client I always get forbidden. Is this flow supported with OAuth2.0?